# Passing data to local storage

Tags: selenium, webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I'm using Cucumber with Java and I'm trying to pass a value to local storage. I'm using also WebDriverManager and when I try to execute some script with JavaScripExecutor, another instance of a browser is opened.

I tried to implement the JavaScriptExecutor in the WebDriverManager but I got the same result as before.

```
public class WebDriverManager {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private static DriverType driverType;
    private static EnvironmentType environmentType;
    private static final String CHROME_DRIVER_PROPERTY = "webdriver.chrome.driver";
    private JavascriptExecutor js;

    public WebDriverManager() {
        driverType = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getBrowser();
        environmentType = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getEnvironment();
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        if(driver == null) driver = createDriver();
        return driver;
    }

    public JavascriptExecutor getJavaScriptExecutor() {
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        return js;
    }

    private WebDriver createDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        switch (environmentType) {
            case LOCAL : driver = createLocalDriver();
                break;
            case REMOTE : driver = createRemoteDriver();
                break;
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

I want to be able to use this executor in the already existing browser instance.

Comment: The problem lies somewhere else. Show us how you invoke the method `getJavaScriptExecutor`

Comment: Are you calling "getDriver" first?  If so, the driver is null and it's opening a new driver. (Which launches the browser.)

Comment: I'm calling getDriver() and later in another method I'm calling getJavaScriptExecutor() - which causes to open another browser. How can I pin JaveScriptExecutor to already existing instance of WebDriver? 

`public void heAddsTokenToLocalStorage() {
        js = driverManager.getJavaScriptExecutor();
        pageObjectManager.getWebDriverHelperPage().heAddsTokenToLocalStorage();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from a team member and we figured it out already.

```
public WebDriverManager() throws MalformedURLException {
        driverType = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getBrowser();
        environmentType = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getEnvironment();
        driver = createDriver();
    }
```

By passing driver variable to constructor and by creating appropriate constructors in classes I managed to make JavaScriptExecutor use already existing instance of a WebDriver. Example:

```
JavascriptExecutor js;

    public AcceptanceHelper(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        this.js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    }
```